# RDLC report Error "Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope."

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I need to display some value on textbox which this value will receive from Tablix.

But It's error this messesge

```
    The Value expression for the text box‘TextBoxName’ refers to the report item ‘NameOfTexboxInTablix’.
     Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope. 
      Letters in the names of report items must use the correct case.
```

In hidden tablix has a cell named "NameOfTexboxInTablix" which it use expression for getting value like this

```
    =Lookup(Fields!SEQ_NO.Value,"NO_2",Fields!PROCESS_CODE.Value, "PART_PROCESS")
```

And I have three Textbox (outside tablix) . Three textbox use for display
a value from first row, second row and third rows of dataset.

-Textbox1 will show "PROCESS_CODE" of the first row.

-Textbox2  will show "PROCESS_CODE" of the second row.

-Textbox3 will show "PROCESS_CODE" of  the third row.

So I refer to a cell which it' is textbox in tablix. Textbox named **"NameOfTexboxInTablix"**. Textbox1,2 and 3 will refer by this expression

```
         =ReportItems!NameOfTexboxInTablix.Value
```

But It's error.

**How to solved this problem without combind dataset?**

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem. 
My hidden Tablix was made to use a Lookup function. 
Sometimes a Tablix will automatically create a grouping in the window below the designer (Row Groups). It is named "Details"

So I have solved this problem by deleting this "Details" Group.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Referencing to textbox which is part of  grouping, in other tablix cannot be done.